# How can I maintain a Structured URL whilst generating the flatter `/product-name/` variant as well?

Tags: wordpress, url, woocommerce

I am creating an eCommerce website, powered by WordPress, with WooCommerce powering the shopping functionality.

The website will have many Products; likely to fit multiple Product Categories.  As such, typical URL structures, will be:

```
www.example.com/product-category-a/product-a/
www.example.com/product-category-b/product-a/
```

The above URL structure follows a Hierarchy; something I wish to keep for both User Experience and Search Engine Optimisation.

> There is much debate over whether Search Engines prefer a structured
>   or flat URL structure.  Regardless, I feel a structured URL is easier
>   to maintain, analyse and preserve a sense of order.

The downside of this hierarchical approach, is the issue of duplicate content.  Keeping to the above examples, I would like to `rel=canonical` to their respective flat Product URL structure, as follows:

```
www.example.com/product-a/
```

The problem, is how am I able to maintain the Category Hierarchical URL structure whilst also being able to create the flatter `/product-a/` variant as well?  At present, I have to choose between one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, all I had to do was ...

1. Ensure `/%category%/` was entered into the Product Permalink.
2. In the event that a Product was within a Child Category, only select the Child Category and not the Parent Category.  If the Parent Category is selected, as well as the Child Category, the Child Category does not appear in the URL.
3. Even though the Product Permalink is set to `/%category%/`, as to generate the Hierarchical Product URL, the `/product/product-name/` is still generated regardless.
4. Implement `rel=canonical` as you would normally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use breadcrumbs with schema markup to determine the hierarchy of your site. You don't need a flat URL structure but evidence shows that shorter URLs have higher CTR (Click Through Rate). This article provides some data around that (https://www.getelastic.com/short-urls).

So, keep some URL structural hierarchy but use micro data and breadcrumbs to determine the structure of the site. For example:

example.com/category/product = Use this as the URL

Rather than:

example.com/category/sub-category/product-type/product

But use this as the breadcrumb:
Home> category> sub-category> product-type> product

This maintains user navigability and defines your sites structure to Google. You can reinforce this bu using multiple XML sitemaps that keep the true structure rather than the displayed URL.